# How to use select() to specify src config of a lower level library dependency

Tags: bazel

I have a `top_level_library` I build with `bazel build`, which has a series of dependencies, and 3 levels down it has a dependency `library_a` that has options for `srcs` depending on which cpu architecture I'm building for, arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, etc. I can't seem to get the top level option passed down all the way to the `library_a` to specify the source, bazel complains that the configurable attribute doesn't match the configuration passed in

I've tried naming the config values to `fat_apk_cpu`, I'm aware I can get bazel to build for the correct cpu architecture with that flag after `bazel build //:top_level_library --fat_apk_cpu=x86`, and that works fine for everything until I get to this `library_a`, where I don't use bazel to build it, just grab the resources from the correct places.

here's my `top_level_library`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "top_level",
    srcs = glob([
        ...,
    ]),
    deps = [
        ":library_a"
    ],
)
```

for simplicity sake, I'll put the dependency just one level down, but in reality it's 3 levels down

```
cc_library(
  name = "library_a",
  srcs = select({
    ":armeabi_v7a" : 
        ["lib/armeabi-v7a/lib.so"],
    ":x86" : 
        ["lib/x86/lib.so"],
    ":arm64_v8a" : 
        ["lib/arm64-v8a/lib.so"],
  })
)
```

along with 3 config settings, one for each option:

```
config_setting(
    name = "x86",
    values = {"cpu": "x86"},
)

config_setting(
    name = "armeabi_v7a",
    values = {"cpu": "armeabi_v7a"},
)

config_setting(
    name = "arm64_v8a",
    values = {"cpu": "arm64_v8a"},
)
```

the error message is as follows:

```
Configurable attribute "srcs" doesn't match this configuration (would a default condition help?).
Conditions checked:
 //library-a/build:armeabi_v7a
 //library-a/build:x86
 //library-a/build:arm64_v8a
```

Any tips on how to resolve this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `--fat_apk_cpu` only works when building an `android_binary` target. When building anything else, only the value of `--cpu` matters (including building `cc_library` targets by themselves that might also be in the deps of an `android_binary`). armeabi_v7a, arm64_v8a, and x86 are not any of the default values of `--cpu`, so it will have to be set on the command line when building this target, or provide a default value for the `select`.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response! So you're saying I can't be running a script that has `bazel build` but I'd have to call it from the command line? Is there any way around this? The goal of this is to build for every architecture automatically

Comment: And thanks for pointing that out, I am in fact building an `android_binary` target which has a dependency on the `cc_library`

Comment: Could you give more details about what "where I don't use bazel to build it, just grab the resources from the correct places." means?

Comment: Also, if you're running bazel from a script, you can just add whatever command line flags you need to the invocation of bazel within the script

Comment: I've tried `bazel build //:top_level_library --cpu=x86`, still getting the same error message, any ideas? To answer your question, I phrased it badly, the `cc_library` is already built with the binaries provided to me, it's the library one level above it that's dependent on this has a reference to it in its deps, which lead to me creating this BUILD file with the select sources

Comment: Setting cpu like that should work, so I'm not sure what the problem might be. A minimal repro might be helpful.

Comment: Also, there will be another problem here, where once the select() problem is solved, you'll need to set a toolchain that knows about an "x86" cpu. The default toolchain doesn't use that name. You can set the target toolchain to the android one with `--crosstool_top=@androidndk//:default_crosstool --host_crosstool_top=@local_config_cc//:toolchain`, assuming you have an `android_ndk_repository` with the name "androidndk" in your workspace file.

Comment: I managed to solve this with a custom flag instead of cpu, thanks for your pointers!